# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in React JS on Meteor App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, oauth, cors

I'm using ReactJS for the Front end rendering of my site and using Meteor JS for server and everything else.

I'm calling a OAuth API on the client side...I get the following result:

```
Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's your own API, add a CORS header allowing that origin. Here's an example that allows every origin. It must be run on the server:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

If it's not your API, make the request on the server (Servers can ignore CORS) via a Meteor method and return the result to the client